# Change output depending on State in VHDL

Tags: vhdl

My output has to be high if my state is either F or H, i've written this:

```
z <= '1' WHEN y = (F OR H) ELSE '0' ;
```

But this doesn't work. I've also tried writing it like:

```
IF y = F THEN
    z <= '1' ;
ELSIF y = H THEN
    z <= '1' ;
ELSE
    z <= '0';
END IF ;
```

But now get Error 10500 in Quartus 2 so whats wrong with my syntax or is there a better way to write it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My best guess given so little information, like what "not working" means...

F and H are of some type that does not have boolean operators defined on it; therefore `(F or H)` is meaningless.

Now ... `Y = F` is a boolean expression, so is `Y = H` so you can say

```
z <= '1' WHEN (y = F) OR (y = H) ELSE '0' ;
```

and (assuming this is outside a process) it might do what you expect (assuming Y, F,H are the same or compatible type)

The second form will also work, but only as part of a process...

Answer (score 3):

The first one should be written this way:

```
z <= '1' WHEN (y = F) OR (y = H) ELSE '0';
```

The second one needs to be inside a process:

```
PROCESS (y) BEGIN
  IF y = F THEN
    z <= '1';
  ELSIF y = H THEN
    z <= '1';
  ELSE
    z <= '0';
  END IF;
END PROCESS;
```